# is there a right way to deploy flask app to search data from using pickle file on aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, pickle

herer i have flask appliction to perform search using pickle data , my code works on local host but not on AWS server it show attribute error. what i found out is loading pickle file under **if **name** == '**main**':** going to solve but still got same error

on webpage it show
Internal Server Error

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

on console it shows following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myfit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myfit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myfit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myfit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myfit/app.py", line 62, in search
    docs = pickle.load(file)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Document' on <module '__main__' from '/home/ubuntu/myfit/bin/flask'>
```

heres the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import numpy as np
import json
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import faiss
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')



    # Load the JSON data

model = SentenceTransformer("multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1", device="cpu")  
def generate_embedding(text):
    response = model.encode([text])
    return np.array(response[0])




class VectorStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.documents = []
        self.embeddings = np.empty((0,384))  # Initialize as empty array

def add_to_store(self, document):
# Append the document to the list of documents
    self.documents.append(document)

# Generate the embedding for the document
    response = generate_embedding(document.content)

# Concatenate the response with the existing embeddings vertically
    self.embeddings = np.vstack((self.embeddings, response))


class Document:
    def __init__(self, title, url, content):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.content = content
        
 



@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])

    
def search():
    query = request.form.get('query')
    myresults = []
    with open('docs.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        docs = pickle.load(file)
    store = []
    store = VectorStore()
    with open('output_data.json', 'r') as f:
        myvector = json.load(f)

    feature_batch=np.array(myvector)

# Create an index with the same dimension as the embeddings
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(feature_batch.shape[1])

# Add the embeddings to the index


    index.add(feature_batch)

    faiss.write_index(index, 'index.faiss')



# Generate embedding for the given query




# Set the similarity threshold
    similarityThreshold = 1

    # Generate embedding for the given query
    query_embedding = generate_embedding(query)

# Search for similar embeddings in the index
    distances, results = index.search(np.array([query_embedding]), k=3)

    # Filter the results based on the similarity threshold
    filtered_results = []
    for i, distance in zip(results[0], distances[0]):
        if distance <= similarityThreshold:
            filtered_results.append(i)

    # Print the content of the documents
    for i in filtered_results:
        myresults.append(docs[i].content) 



# Perform a simple search by checking if the query is in any data item
    return render_template('index.html', myresults=myresults)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

small change i did loading pickle file under **if **name** == '**main**':** but still got same error

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import numpy as np
import json
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import faiss
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')



    # Load the JSON data

model = SentenceTransformer("multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1", device="cpu")  
def generate_embedding(text):
    response = model.encode([text])
    return np.array(response[0])




class VectorStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.documents = []
        self.embeddings = np.empty((0,384))  # Initialize as empty array

def add_to_store(self, document):
# Append the document to the list of documents
    self.documents.append(document)

# Generate the embedding for the document
    response = generate_embedding(document.content)

# Concatenate the response with the existing embeddings vertically
    self.embeddings = np.vstack((self.embeddings, response))


class Document:
    def __init__(self, title, url, content):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.content = content
        
 



@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])

    
def search():
    query = request.form.get('query')
    myresults = []
    store = []
    store = VectorStore()

    feature_batch=np.array(myvector)

# Create an index with the same dimension as the embeddings
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(feature_batch.shape[1])

# Add the embeddings to the index


    index.add(feature_batch)

    faiss.write_index(index, 'index.faiss')



# Generate embedding for the given query




# Set the similarity threshold
    similarityThreshold = 1

    # Generate embedding for the given query
    query_embedding = generate_embedding(query)

# Search for similar embeddings in the index
    distances, results = index.search(np.array([query_embedding]), k=3)

    # Filter the results based on the similarity threshold
    filtered_results = []
    for i, distance in zip(results[0], distances[0]):
        if distance <= similarityThreshold:
            filtered_results.append(i)

    # Print the content of the documents
    for i in filtered_results:
        myresults.append(docs[i].content) 



# Perform a simple search by checking if the query is in any data item
    return render_template('index.html', myresults=myresults)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('docs.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        docs = pickle.load(file)

    with open('output_data.json', 'r') as f:
        myvector = json.load(f)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, i had to make simple change

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

turns out to there's difference between **flask run** and **python app.py** command in **AWS** sever.

i had issuse with **WSGI** while running with  **flask run**.

if you launch with the python executable by running python app.py or similar, then anything inside the if **name** == '**main**': block is executed without any isuse.